# how we plan for Windows updates in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, windows-server-2012-r2

we have plan to install Windows updates in production SharePoint farm 2013,
which services and functionalities these updates will impact mostly and how we plan for Windows updates in SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check with corresponding KB articles for the update, what fix include in it and which module it will touch. i.e check this [KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2919355)

Now for SharePoint, we never enabled the automatic updates for windows but we plan it. Typically, we do the following things

- Stop the SharePoint Timer and Admin services.
- Unshceudle our Search Crawl
- Stop the Profile Sync.
- Stop the IIS

Now apply the updates and then start the service and test it. Yes we perform this in our qa farm 1st.

Comment: windows updates for OS and also any security updates for framework etc cause any issues to running sharepoint 2013 farm at the moment of new windows updates in august 2016?

Comment: it may, but as of now, we dont have any issue so far in 2013 or 2016. But testing is the key, you can catch more issue from there